# Angular Speech Recognition function is getting called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

I am trying to  use [Angular-Speech-Recognition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kamiazya/ngx-speech-recognition) in Angular application. Below are my html and component ts code. My speech is correctly getting assigned to `this.message`.  My requirement is,  after I complete the speech, I want to call `this.getSearchResults(this.message);`. But whats happening is for each word in my speech the function call `this.getSearchResults(this.message)` is happening.

For example, if I speak, `"I forgot my password"`, I expect `this.getSearchResults(this.message)` to be called once with `this.message` as  `"I forgot my password"`. But whats happening is 4 times the function is getting called,  as there are 4 words in my speech (for each word the function `getSearchResults` is getting triggered). How can I fix it?

```
 <fa-icon 
 [icon]="faMicrophone" 
 class="microphone-icon" 
 (click)="listenSpeech()">
 </fa-icon> 

listenSpeech() {
    this.speechSrv
      .listen()
      .pipe(resultList)
      .subscribe((list: SpeechRecognitionResultList) => {
        this.message = list.item(0).item(0).transcript;
       this.getSearchResults(this.message);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never unsubscribe so with every click you're making another subscription. Maybe you want to use `take(1)` to ensure each `.subscribe` is going to be trigger at most once?

```
this.speechSrv
  .listen()
  .pipe(resultList) // Don't know what this is so you might put `take(1)` here instead of using two `pipe()` calls
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe((list: SpeechRecognitionResultList) => {
    this.message = list.item(0).item(0).transcript;
   this.getSearchResults(this.message);
  });
```